# JavaFX TreeItem.TreeModificationEvent<V> event doesn't provide access to (ListChangeListener.Change) change member to get ordering information

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I need to subscribe to Tree Events, so that I can detect changes to children from a TreeView, including ordering changes. The change member of the event seems to have ordering information, but is not available to the developer.

What's the most efficient way to get ordering information from a TreeModicationEvent?

...

```
sourceNode.addEventHandler(TreeItem.<V>childrenModificationEvent(), (TreeItem.TreeModificationEvent<V> event) -> {

            var c =event.getChange(); // <--- This is not available
}
```

...

Comment: go dirty and access the change reflectively is the only option that I know - but beware: even internally, the change is not always set (as far as I remember)

Comment: Ok, I was considering doing that, but do agree that there is no other way to get ordering information? Seems like the API is lacking here as the underlying ListChangeEvent has useful ordering information (at least when it is set)

Comment: Exactly what is the information you're trying to access? If you need to know if the children were sorted then use [`TreeModificationEvent#wasPermutated()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.TreeModificationEvent.html#wasPermutated()). If you need access to the children list then use `event.getTreeItem().getChildren()`. However, if you need to know the range of affected indices then you'll probably have to use reflection.

Comment: yes, range of affected indices is what I want, otherwise calculating the index is quite expensive.